Cypher Query Using APOC cloneNodes Procedure Returns null for output
I am trying to clone a node in Neo4j using the APOC procedure apoc.refactor.cloneNodes. Although the node exists and the query executes without errors, the output is always null. I expect the output to contain the cloned node. Here's the query I am using:
MATCH (n:TestNode {name: "Test"})
WITH collect(n) AS nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.cloneNodes(nodes) YIELD input, output
RETURN input, output

Verified the Node Exists:
I confirmed that the node with name: "Test" exists using the following query:
cypher
Copy code
MATCH (n:TestNode {name: "Test"})
RETURN n


It works for me and returns an output. Can you upload a screen shot of your browser?  Thanks.

I am using neo4j 4.4.16, it is not working there for me ,what version you used to test it?

I am using neo4j version 4.4.3. Thanks.
